# Will SCPlugin work on Mac OS Yosemite (10.10)?

Tags: macos

I'm looking for a svn client for Mac Yosemite (10.10) which is similar to TortoiseSVN on Windows and RabbitSVN on Ubuntu.

I came across SCPlugin, when I could see that its latest version is dated as Feb-2010.

Would like to know if it works fine on Yosemite?
(Or)
Are there any other substitute svn clients for the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like it's broken in Yosemite. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6607645

Answer (score 1):

SCPlugin is not working on recent OSX / macOS because the finder does no longer support plugins.
Try free svnx or xversion